# create matrix using scanner enter row by row in java

Tags: java

I want to create a matrix like this way:

```
Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: 4 5
Enter the array:
3 4 5.5 4 5 (enter)
1 3.5 1.5 4 5 (enter)
6.5 1.5 2.5 5 1 (enter)
4 3 1 4 4.4 (enter)
```

then local the smallest value's location in this matrix, but I already stuck in the first step

```
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        double numList[][] = new double[row][col];
        System.out.print("Rnter the number if rows and columns of the array: ");
        row = input.nextInt();
        col = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the array:");
```

what I have already tried is here,
Is there any method? THANK YOU GUYS

Comment: What is the exact problem with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Scanner.nextDouble()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-nextdouble-method) to read the next double value.

```java
   import java.util.Scanner;

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: ");
   int row = input.nextInt();
   int col = input.nextInt();
        
   double numList[][] = new double[row][col];
        
   System.out.println("Enter the array:");
   for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
          numList[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
      }
   }
```